# jquerymobile, update dynamically a page and reset scroll position

Tags: jquery-mobile, scroll, reload

I'm trying to dynamically update the content of a page with jquery mobile ( `$('#testpage').page('destroy').page();` ), and reset the scroll position ( `$.mobile.silentScroll(0);` ).

It works but for a few milliseconds, jquery shows the new content scrolled down at the old position. I wish to show the new content directly scrolled at the top of the page.

There must be a parameter in jquery that remembers the scroll position when you call `$('#testpage').page('destroy').page();`, and I wish to reset this parameter.

Maybe I'm having the wrong approach, and I should use 2 separated divs for the 2 pages.

The reason I'm doing this is because I want the hash in the url being the same for the 2 pages, and I don't want the user being able to go back to the previous page with the browser back action. If I can achieve this with 2 separated divs, that would be fine too.

Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate : http://jsfiddle.net/EKFSy/2/

Comment: Would this help? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/zsNDV/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `$.mobile.silentScroll(0);` with `$.mobile.changePage( $('#testpage') , {allowSamePageTransition:true} );` and it worked.

Note that I also tried to play with `$.mobile.urlHistory.getActive().lastScroll`. It was not necessary in my case to set it to zero (because it seems changePage on the same page already reset the scroll position), but that might be a useful value to play with if you want to change the scroll positions in your history.

http://jsfiddle.net/EKFSy/3/